# npm as a build tool

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, npm

I recently read a great article outlining the downside of using Grunt/Gulp;
which in turns offers leveraging the "npm scripts" approach.

Eventually I found this article: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

I took a shot and tried to implement the as described in the article,
and came across a two questions:

Question #1:

```
$ npm run build:js ( actual command is: "browserify src/javascript/someModule.js" )

// ----------- Why these two lines are added to the stdout ? -------- //
> my-new-app@1.0.0 build:js /Users/elad.chen/Projects/incapsula/daedalus/new-app
> browserify src/javascript/core/sidebar.js
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports = function() {
    console.log("hi")
};
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

I then realized that npm -s, --silent or even --loglevel flags 
can resolve that.

So, if I type "npm run build:js -s" in console, the stdout doesn't include
the redundant logs, But, If I simply add one of the flags to the actual task value, e.g:

> "build:js": "browserify src/javascript/core/sidebar.js --silent"

I still get that extra log info.

Question #2:
When I used Gulp I was able to add breakpoints and debug any running task with ease since I'm using Intellij Idea.

How can I debug when using npm scripts as the build tool?

Comment: Have you managed to work out a way to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid not.. I just left it and opted to use Gulp.